# Print list items without flatMap

Tags: scala

I have this [scala program](http://goo.gl/XzGDLa) that does not compile, why is that? I'm trying to print all the numbers in the list/sublist without using flatMap:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {

  def test() = {
    val numbs = List ((1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3))
    val a = for {
      i <- numbs
      j <- i
    } yield j
    println(a)
  }

  test()

}
```

This is the error:

```
HelloWorld.scala:7: error: value map is not a member of (Int, Int, Int)                                                                                               
      j <- i                                                                                                                                                                    
           ^                                                                                                                                                                    
one error found
```

It should print `List (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)`

Comment: How do you want to print your output? Just the Tuples or all values in the list?

Comment: It should print List (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no map defined for tuples. You need to create a List from a tuple3. Here's one way you can do it:

```
def test() = {
  val numbs = List((1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3))
  val a = for {
    i <- numbs
    j <- List(i._1, i._2, i._3)
  } yield j
  println(a)
}

test() // prints List(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over a tuple using the usual methods. Tuples are there to represent combinations of different things, iterating over them is typically not useful. If you really have to, you can do it by index:

```
val a = for {
  i <- numbs
  j <- 0 until i.productArity
} yield i.productElement(j)
```

But this really seems only useful if you are doing something very generic, like formatting a tuple for textual output. Otherwise, you should rather keep your data as a List of Lists.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the other answers there is no map defined for Tuples. If you don't need to use a `List[Tuples]`, a solution is to use your variable `numbs` as:

`val numbs = List(List(1,1,1), List(2,2,2), List(3,3,3)))`

And your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist using tuples you can also use the productIterator like this:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {

  def test() = {
    val numbs = List((1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3))
    val a = for {
      i <- numbs
      j <- i.productIterator
    } yield j
    println(a)
  }

  test()
}
```

But maybe it's better to consider List of lists instead.